# How to convert rdd to nested json in pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am a newbie and I have a data in the following format

Category, Subcategory, Name

```
Food,Thai,Restaurant A
Food,Thai,Restaurant B
Food, Chinese, Restaurant C
Lodging, Hotel, Hotel A
```

I want the data to be in the following format

```
{Category : Food , Subcategories : [ {subcategory : Thai , names : [Restaurant A , Restaurant B] }, {subcategory : Chinese , names : [Restaurant C]}]}

{Category : Hotel , Subcategories : [ {subcategory : Lodging , names : [Hotel A] }]}
```

Can someone please help me how to solve this using pyspark RDD?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here the helpful solution:

create a window function to collect the names groupBy Category and Subcategory

```
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  from pyspark.sql import Window

  groupByCateWind = Window.partitionBy("Category", "Subcategory")

    finalDf = df.withColumn("names", F.collect_list("Name").over(groupByCateWind)) \
        .withColumn("Subcategories", F.struct("Subcategory", "names")) \
        .groupBy("Category").agg(F.collect_set("Subcategories").alias("Subcategories")).toJSON()
```

1. collect the names groupBy above Window function
2. create Subcategories column with Struct type using Subcategory and names columns.
3. Again do group By Category and collect Subcategory column values.

Output like below:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Category":"Food","Subcategories":[{"Subcategory":"Thai","names":["Restaurant A","Restaurant B"]},{"Subcategory":" Chinese","names":[" Restaurant C"]}]}|
|{"Category":"Lodging","Subcategories":[{"Subcategory":" Hotel","names":[" Hotel A"]}]}                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```